# How to parse an item in a list containing two floats and omit its parentheses in Python

Tags: python, list

So what I have is a list containing floats stored like so:

```
points = [(0.06 , -4.00), (3.76, 0.02), (7.53, 0.09), (26.28, 1.15)]
```

So `index[0] == (0.06, -4.00)`

and I would like to pass them one by one to a function that accepts parameters in the format

```
Point(x,y)
```

so at first I thought I had a solution with

```
for item in points:
    p = Point(item)
```

I quickly realised that is really only providing the function with

```
Point((0.06, -4.00))
```

which leaves the function wanting one more parameter, seeing as it thinks that is only the 'x' variable. I have seen string stripping, but I can't seem to convert the indices of Points back to float after I am done stripping. I think it may be due to the comma interfering.

Some help or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
for x, y in points:
    p = Point(x, y)
```

or [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
for item in points:
    p = Point(*item)
```

Answer (score 1):

`points[0]` is equal to `(0.06 , -4.00)`, so `points[0][0]` is equal to 0.06 and `points[0][1]` is equal to -4.00.

```
for item in points:
    p = Point(item[0],item[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpacking here.

```
for item in points:
    p = Point(*item)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for letting me know this method is called unpacking. Love it